# toString() method error

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, tostring

```
public class X {
// some fields
private Route[] tabT = new Route[50]; // [1]

public String toString() {
    int i;
    String descT = "";
    for (i = 0; i < tabT.length; i++)
        descT += tabT[i].toString();
    String description;
    description = "MESSAGE " + lastName
            + "\nMESSAGE " + firstName
            + "\nMESSAGE " + year
            + "\nMESSAGE " + address
            + "\nMESSAGE " + number
            + "\nMESSAGE " + descT
            + "\n";
    return description;
}
```

My class contains some fields including a list of objects from another class `tabT`. In `toString()` method, I want to show those fields and the fields of the other object but I don't know why it shows an error. When I make a tab of on element it doesn't show an error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Chauffeur.toString(Chauffeur.java:38)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:821)
    at AutoSuperieur.main(AutoSuperieur.java:6)
```

It's exactly on this line `descT += tabT[i].toString();`

Comment: Can you post more code? Namely around tabT. It appears to be null.

Comment: It's likely that `tabT` or one of its elements is `null`.

Comment: btw, you shouldn't use String to concat man strings. You'd better use StringBuilder

Comment: Why don't you use an ArrayList instead of an array? Given your algorithm, it's obvious that some elements of the tabT array are null. So you should check that before calling `toString()` on them.

Comment: @JBNizet Because array is more familiar to me. I can't use ArrayList very well

Comment: Then you should definitely learn using it. You're reinventing the wheel and making your own life difficult. Lists are essential data structure that every Java programmer uses every day.

Comment: @JBNizet I will. But, what about this problem?

Comment: Even when I remove = "" from descT. It says « the local variable descT may not have been initialized »

Comment: show  `AutoSuperieur.main`, line 6 please

Comment: @RiaD Check what i've added

Comment: @mpluse: I told you about the problem, and several others also did: you have null elements in your array, but are calling toString() on these null elements. Check they're not null before calling toString on them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (tabT != null) 
  descT += (tabT[i] == null?"":tabT[i].toString());
```

To make sure you understand it how it works. You've got `NullPointerException` in the `toString()`. Then you should check what variable could be `null` value. After editing your question I see that `tabT` is initialized, so the `if (tabT != null)` check is not nessesary but it protect the code above from the `NullPointerException` because in the second line I use reference `tabT` that might not been initialized.  Next the operator [] dereferncing the elements of the array that could be `null` value. The ternary operator `?` checks that value and if it's `null` then returns `""` otherwise `toString()` the value of the element. To make this call possible the value should not be `null`. Then I use grouping `()` to return the result string to the concatenate operator `+=` that incrementally concatenates old and new values.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `String.valueOf()` to handle nulls.

```
descT += String.valueOf(tabT[i]);
```

Besides, operator `+=` performes copying(at least in general case). You should better use `StringBuilder` to handle big concatenations.